# Using Laravel bundle with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, laravel, laravel-3

I want to use Laravel Bootstrapper bundle http://bundles.laravel.com/bundle/bootstrapper with my CodeIgniter application.

How can i utilize autoloader functionality to use Bootstrapper bundle code in CodeIgniter in native PHP 5 fashion.

```
Button::make('Abc')->with_icon('ok');
```

Do you suggest to convert Bootstrapper bundle in CodeIgniter library or we can use it as it is.

I am using bootstrap for creating views, thus already including bootstrap specific css, js & images.

Please help, so that the bundle can be used with CodeIgniter

Comment: Is you intention to create the black whole of bad practices? That thing might end up destroying the internet.

Comment: @tereško - what do you suggest then?

Comment: I think he is suggesting you don't do it and I'd have to agree. Frameworks aren't typically mix n' match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why? It's not designed to work with CI, you'll probably have to mess about alot to get it working. See one of the many versions available for CI here https://github.com/vesparny/codeigniter-html5boilerplate-twitter-bootstrap.

Further more, I dont see any great advantage of having a bootstrap CI integration, if you do then go for it but I just use my own customised bootstrap and load it in as normal in template/view files. Works just fine and keeps all those UI/view bits and pieces separate for designers/Front-end coders who panic at the sight of php.

All this work trying to keep design, function and layout separate and people go to great effort to ruin it with something like this.